# Can't plot contour plot getting an error saying A Qhull internal error has occurred

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot a contour plot but when I use the griddata method in scipy.interpolatem, I getting this error: `A Qhull internal error has occurred`

Here is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.interpolate import griddata
    import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
    
    from read_db import setup_data, get_lat, get_lon, get_param
    
    
    setup_data()
    
    param = get_param()
    lat = get_lat()
    lon = get_lon()

    x = np.array(lon)
    y = np.array(lat)
    z = np.array(param)
    
    xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
    yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 100)
    
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
    
    Z = griddata((x, y), z, (X, Y), method='cubic')
    
    plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
    plt.show()
```

When I executing the code I get the following an error:

```
File "C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\GUI\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\ndgriddata.py", line 264, in griddata
    ip = CloughTocher2DInterpolator(points, values, fill_value=fill_value,
  File "interpnd.pyx", line 908, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.__init__
  File "qhull.pyx", line 1841, in scipy.spatial.qhull.Delaunay.__init__
  File "qhull.pyx", line 357, in scipy.spatial.qhull._Qhull.__init__
scipy.spatial.qhull.QhullError: QH6421 qhull internal error (qh_maxsimplex): qh.MAXwidth required for qh_maxsimplex.  Used to estimate determinate

While executing:  | qhull d Qt Q12 Qc Qz Qbb
Options selected for Qhull 2019.1.r 2019/06/21:
  run-id 1767753654  delaunay  Qtriangulate  Q12-allow-wide  Qcoplanar-keep
  Qz-infinity-point  Qbbound-last  _pre-merge  _zero-centrum  Qinterior-keep
  Pgood  _max-width  0  Error-roundoff 1.1e-13  _one-merge 7.6e-13
  Visible-distance 2.2e-13  U-max-coplanar 2.2e-13  Width-outside 4.3e-13
  _wide-facet 1.3e-12  _maxoutside 8.7e-13

A Qhull internal error has occurred.  Please send the input and output to
qhull_bug@qhull.org. If you can duplicate the error with logging ('T4z'), please
include the log file.
```

Here is my values for lat, lon, param

```
    param = [212.51, 212.46, 212.48, 212.87, 212.76, 212.73, 212.6, 212.61, 212.72, 212.62, 212.38, 212.29, 212.17, 212.19, 212.13, 212.29, 212.31, 212.4, 212.39, 212.43, 212.55, 212.59, 212.72, 212.58, 212.58, 212.33, 212.24, 212.4, 212.45, 212.57, 212.42]
    lat = [9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0]
    lon = [78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0, 78.0]
```

I am new to this kind of stuff and don't really understand what's happening to cause the error.

Comment: Your Lon and lat are not going to produce a reasonable grid, are they?

Comment: @JodyKlymak no i don't think so, the data is the temperature at the coordinates of each day in a month my assignment was to plot a contour with the data

Comment: You have one value for latitude, and you have one value for longitude.  How do you expect to contour that?